# A set in the extended real numbers that has no supremum

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In baby Rudin, it is proved that if an ordered set that includes the integers Z has the Least Upper Bound Property, then it is archimedean. That is, if every nonempty set that is bounded above has a least upper bound, then for every x $\in$ R, $\exists$ n $\in$ Z s.t. n > x.

Now, the extended real line, that is R $\cup$ {+$\infty , -\infty$}, clearly is not archimedean, so it should not have the LUB property. However, every set is bounded above in the extended real line, and every set seems to have a least upper bound in the extended reals. For example, if E is a subset of R with no upper bound, then $\infty$ would be the sup of E in the extended reals. Any ideas on how to resolve these apparent contradiction?

Comment: What is the exact statement of the theorem in Rudin?

Comment: What exactly does "archimedean" mean in the context of the extended real line? I doubt it is defined.

Comment: If x,y in R, x > 0, then there is a positive integer n s.t. nx > y. This is from page 9 chpt.1 in my version, and I'm pretty sure it implies the statement in my question.

Comment: @Auburn: But what is the statement of the *theorem* that you paraphrase in your first sentence.

Comment: The theorem in Rudin is as above. If x,y in R, x > 0, then there is a positive integer n s.t. nx > y. They only use the fact that R contains Z and has the LUB property in the proof. They use this to illustrate an implication of the LUB property. This is also their definition of archimedean, so archimedean would mean the same thing in the context of the extended reals.

Comment: Let x = 1, and the theorem is as I stated it.

Comment: There's a hidden hypothesis in there: Perhaps the right statement is "If an ordered *subset of the reals* that includes the integers has the LUB property, then it is archimidean." Or maybe "If an ordered *field* that includes the integers has the LUB property, then..." Or maybe any of a number of other possibilities.

Comment: You evidently have a different edition from mine, which doesn’t mention the Archimedean property at all. Thus, I can’t read the proof to see what is actually being assumed. @JohnHughes has mentioned the two likeliest possibilities. The extended reals aren’t a field, and I’m sure that carefully tracing through the argument would show where it fails when applied to the extended reals.

Comment: You say the false theorem in the OP is stated in Rudin, but the words you use sound like it's *not* stated in Rudin at all, but instead something you have synthesized by looking over the proof of some other theorem that is *actually* stated in Rudin.